# Can maven print a shorter reactor summary?

Tags: maven

When a multiproject maven build completes, a summary of all the components is printed as the final output. It looks like this:

```
[INFO] Compiling 5 source files to C:\project\target\classes
----------
1. ERROR in C:\project\src\main\java\com\example\Foo.java (at line 100)
        foo.bar();
            ^^^
The method bar() is undefined
----------
3 problems (3 errors)[INFO] ------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] ---------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Found 1 errors and 0 warnings.
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] ---------------------------------------------------
[INFO] -----------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Component 1 ... SUCCESS [1.000s]
[INFO] Component 2 ... FAILURE [2.000s]
[INFO] Component 3 ... SKIPPED
[INFO] -----------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] -----------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.000s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Jun 14 12:10:36 EDT 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 579M/812M
[INFO] -----------------------------------------
```

I have a very large project with over a hundred components. If there is a failure, I would like the error message and its context to be very near the bottom of the output. Is there a way to make this summary shorter? Instead of listing all the components I just want it to show the last component and whether it succeeded or failed.

Comment: I don't know, but it's a good question (+1) ... but I'm pretty sure there is no way to do that !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had similar issues here. What I do is run `mvn somegoal -l file.log` and then grep through file.log

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. I was trying to figure this out some time ago and unfortunately I didn't find anything. You can't even control logging by ignoring some levels etc.

For me, it worked then processing Maven output with simple Python scipt that just filter this output and gather information that I needed.